# alinear iconos a:link en una lista

Tags: css

como puedo alinear verticalmente los iconos (fontawesome) de una lista ul li independiente de la altura de el li?
gracias

```css
a {
  background: red;
  display:block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-decoration:none;
}
li {
   background: gray;
   list-style:none;
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>Alinear iconos middle</li>
   <li><a href="" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>Alinear iconos middle</li>
   <li><a href="" class="fa fa-envelope"></a>Alinear iconos middle</li>
   <li><a href="" class="fa fa-camera-retro"></a>Alinear iconos middle</li>
  </ul>
    
    <p> porque el texto si se alinea verticalmente en el middle y los iconos no?<br>
    como soluciono esto. gracias</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hurra, Flexbox!

```css
a {
  background: red;
  display:block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration:none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
li {
   background: gray;
   list-style:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <ul>
   <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>Alinear iconos middle</li>
   <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>Alinear iconos middle</li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Infinitas gracias, me sirvió mucho